# objective-c - Attach UIImage to share

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, share

I have my issues with the following code. Only thing I want is that also an image is attached to the share message.

```
NSString *textToShare = @"I'm feeling good!";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iamgross.de"];
UIImage *bestImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bestIcon"];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[bestImage, textToShare, myWebsite];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Here your non-main thread.
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

        NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                       UIActivityTypePrint,
                                       UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                       UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                       UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                       UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                       UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Here you returns to main thread.
            [loading alertIsDismissed:^{
                [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            }];
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's the point of creating the `UIActivityViewController` on a background thread? You shouldn't do that. I know you presenting it on the main thread but there is no reason (and it could be bad) to create it on a background thread.

Comment: and why shouldn't I? You know these stuff is really slow so I wanted to make it faster and it is...

Comment: UI code must be on the main thread. It's not thread safe. And the 3 lines you have on the background are not slow at all.

Comment: okay I've updated the code. Any idea how to attach a uiimage?

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)shareText:(NSString *)text andImage:(UIImage *)image andUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (text) {
        [sharingItems addObject:text];
    }
    if (image) {
        [sharingItems addObject:itemImage];
    }

    if (url) {
        [sharingItems addObject:url];
    }

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
    [activityController setValue:@"Look at what I found" forKey:@"subject"];
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: trying to call it like this  `[self shareText:@"lalal" andImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bestIcon"] andUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.iamgross.de"]];` but I got some issues with the `itemImage`. So I changed it to just `image` but then there wasn't a website or an image

Comment: I tested it and used it in my apps. different share activities use different sharing items. You might also have problem with the url encoding.